# How do I create a UI for a Many-to-Many relationship?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

Can anyone advise on the best way to create a UI for establishing Many-to-Many relationships ?

Lets use an example from a previous question  List <<-->> Patient.

I can create two separate Table Views, one for Lists and another for Patients which will allow the user to create Lists and Patients using two separately created Array Controllers (Lists and Patients), one linked to the List entity and other linked to the Patient entity.

Now I would like to be able to add/remove Patients from a List by creating an Table View that shows only Patients in the selected List.  To do this I create a Array Controller (ListPatients) linked to the entity Patient with a Content Set binding to Lists.selection.patients.

Now things stop working nicely from here on....

If I bind a button to the ListPatients.add method then a NEW Patient gets created - there seems to be no way to simply add a NEW relationship between an existing Patient and the List.

Ideally what I would like to be able to do is to have a drop down list to select the Patient from.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how best to do this without needing to create a new entity to represent this relationship.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a swapping Master-Detail view where either the `List` table or the `Patient` table is the Master or the Detail at any particular time.

When the `List` is the Master view, selecting a row will cause the Detail view to display all the `Patient` objects in the `rowList.patients` relationship. When the `Patient` is the Master view, selecting a row will cause the Detail view to display all the `List` objects in the `rowPatient.lists` relationship.

You really do want to break up the UI so the users always have a clear idea what the relationship is between the two tables. I would recommend a set of four tables, two each for each Master-Detail setup. That way, the user will also understand what they are looking at.

That will also make it easy to add new objects. Just put an `add new` button under the detail table and the user will understand that clicking it will add a new object to the relationship of the object selected in the Master view.

Comment: TechZen - thanks for that.  The issue I have is how to create a master detail view - lets stick with a List ->> Patient master detail view for now - that allows the user to not only create new Patient objects but that will also allow the user to select an existing Patient object to include in the selected List's list of patients.
Bearing in mind that a Patient can appear in multiple Lists, therefor if I create a Patient object for a selected List object then i also need to be able to select this new Patient object and add it to another List object.

Comment: So how would I construct the Array Controllers, Table Views and Pop-up Lists to deal with this requirement.  Lets stick with the simple case of creating a number of List objects and a separate number of Patient objects. Easy enough with separate Table Views and Array Controllers.
Now what mechanism would one use to allow the user to select a number of Patient objects and add them to a List object ?  I don't see any standard way to do this without resorting to some custom code - say for example to display a list of List objects with a checkbox next to each one.

Comment: That's a bit detailed for a comment. You might want to open another question. I would keep things simple: Just have a table of list objects and table of patient objects keyed to the selected list. Setup another pair of tables the other way. Don't cram so much functionality into small pieces of the UI.